# Wpf Expander togglebutton mouseover to be transparent

Tags: wpf, expander

In Expander icon by default on mouseover their is a color change. I want my exander toggle button not to change color onmouseover.

Please provide some usefull code

Comment: When the WPF Expander icon needs to be changed, the solution is invariably to modify the control template.  It's a fairly simple process to change it, but open-ended questions like this are usually seeking an extended *TUTORIAL* (i.e., Russian Doll Question).  Like, are you using declarative or code-behind?  So can you be more specific and include the types of things that are acceptable as a solution?  Are you familiar with control templates sufficient to accept a minimal snippet?

Comment: @nayas_sub3431732, it is customary on this website for question authors to [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) once their problem has been solved. Users that don't generally accept answers (like you are, according to your [question history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3431732/nayas-sub3431732?tab=questions)) can get shunned by the community because they are essentially denying the answer authors the reputation that they deserved for answering the questions. Please try to accept the answers that help you solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extract the style for the togglebutton of the expander and then comment out the mouseover trigger (which changes the color in your instance).

Default style for a toggle button below. Please refer to the **IsMouseOver** trigger and see how I have commented out the setters.

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <!--<Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>-->
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Thank You for ur quick reply. i got the code. Thank u